# Cross-currency Swaps - discounting used for calculating collateral posting in different currencies

Tags: discounting, cross-currency-basis

When finding the value of a cross currency swap you need to take into account the collateral posting currency of the CSA agreement and adjust the discount factors accordingly, see this reference for example going through the rationale https://insights.londonfs.com/modern-derivatives-pricing-csa-discounting.

My question is: When you're calculating the value of the actual collateral to be posted, would you still use the native currency discount factors or is the collateral posted the same as the present value of the swap, found using the CSA-adjusted discount factors?

It would seem to me that the CSA-adjustments are there to account for the fact that the collateral received is worth less to us if it is in the wrong currency, since we need to then enter into an FX swap to convert it, thus lowering the value of the swap. Then it would make sense that the actual collateral we receive should be unadjusted, and then when we enter into the FX swap we are left with the adjusted value. Meaning that the collateral should then simply be discounted with the native currency, not accounting for the CSA. Is this correct or am I thinking about it the wrong way?